# Mapreduce, MR-IncrementalTask, ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

In a java instance of app engine, I'm using mapreduce to iterate over
a collection of entities to do some summarization.

When I run with 10 shards, I'm getting a lot of these:

```
/mapreduce/workerCallback
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: 
The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
```

My mapper is trying to handle about 70,000 entities, each of which is about 750 bytes.
For each call to my mapper, I do maybe a few dozen datastore reads and maybe two
datastore updates.

I am SURE that my individual entities are nowhere near the 1MB datastore limit.
Running with more shards does not really help.

I noticed that mapreduce adds a few entity types, one of which is MR-IncrementalTask.
When these errors appear, MR-IncrementalTask entities get big, like 800k or 900k.
I suspect that the errors are related to these getting too big.

So, then, why do these get so large, and what sorts of things might I be doing
that contribute to that?

Thanks to all.

Comment: As usual, I am now answering my own question.  This is conjecture, but I think that mapreduce is serializing my mapper class and storing it in MR-IncrementalTask.  Of late, I added some new data to the class (for an optimization).  I think this data was accumulating over the life of the shard.  Taking that data out of the picture has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the mapper class is serialized and written to the datastore between execution of tasks from the task queue. This provides continuity for any member variables of the mapper that are updated while it is running.

To reduce the problems associated with this data getting large, and to lower the overhead or reading and writing it. Newer versions of MapReduce compress this state.